# "North Korea is getting closer to having nuclear weapons."

Tags: grammar

I just heard it from a CNN correspondent, quote, "North Korea is getting closer to having nuclear weapons."

My questions are:

1- I wonder why here " to "  is a preposition rather than infinitive.

2- What is the difference between "to having" and "to have" here?

"North Korea is getting closer to having nuclear weapons."

"North Korea is getting closer to have nuclear weapons."

Are both sentences correct?

Comment: Both are grammatical. Only the first means what CNN meant to convey.   “having nukes” is a state.  “getting closer to have” is an odd thing to say and would mean that NK is approaching in order to have ...

Comment: @Jim Are you sure "closer to have" is idiomatic? It doesn't sound it to me.

Comment: @WS2 - I never said it was idiomatic- I said it was an odd thing to say.  But it’s grammatical.  In other contexts it could be idiomatic:  He’s getting closer to have a look over the edge.

Comment: @Jim 'Both are grammatical' refers to OP's question << "North Korea is getting closer to having nuclear weapons."

"North Korea is getting closer to have nuclear weapons."

Are both sentences correct? >> and is wrong.  The second sentence OP asks about is ungrammatical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Do you not agree that the “in order to have” meaning makes the second grammatical?  As I said, it’s an odd thing to say semantically but it breaks no grammar rules.

Comment: @Jim 'I just heard it from a CNN correspondent' and the source referred to, plus OP's 'What is the difference between "to having" and "to have" **here**?' demand that the 'in order to have' sense is not available here. Introducing it is disingenuous.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Use the first option, *having*

Only **having** is grammatical *and* means that North Korea is approaching the point where they will have nuclear weapons.

The structure of the sentence calls for a *present participle.*

> the form of a verb, ending in -ing in English, which is used in forming continuous tenses, e.g., in I'm thinking, alone in nonfinite clauses, e.g., in sitting here, I haven't a care in the world, as a noun, e.g., in good thinking, and as an adjective, e.g., in running water.

If that sounds confusing or unclear, let's take a closer look at [the options we have](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/have), with the important points in bold.

> *have* - present tense 1st and 2nd person singular, or **present tense 3rd person plural**
>
> *having* - **present participle**
>
> *had* - past tense 1st, 2nd, and 3rd person singular, past tense 3rd person plural, or past participle.
>
> *has* - **present tense 3rd person singular**

We know that North Korea is third person.  We also know that it's singular.  The only thing in question is what tense to use.

We can eliminate **had** offhand because it only deals with past tense, and we can tell that the sentence "North Korea is getting closer to having..." is not about the past.

If we wanted to use present tense, we'd see that present tense 3rd person singular is *has*, as in:

> North Korea **has** a nuclear weapon.

But that doesn't sound quite right in the context of the original sentence, because the word is structured to describe something ongoing, or more specifically, something that is *close to being* ongoing.

> North Korea is getting closer to **has** a nuclear weapon

Sounds wrong, doesn't it?  So we're left choosing between "have" and "having."  But note from the definition outlined above that "have" in 3rd person can only function as *present tense **plural***.

> The countries **have** a nuclear weapon.

It doesn't work in singular, which we recall would use **has**.

> North Korea **have** a nuclear weapon.

Since North Korea is singular third person, the only option we're left with for tense is present participle.  So even if the term *present participle* is difficult to understand, we can deduce that none of the other forms fit.

> North Korea is getting closer to **having** nuclear weapons.

To learn more about *present participle* and understand why it's appropriate in cases like this, google the term or take a look at [this article in Grammarly.](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/participle/)

Comment: This is not a sound answer. The fact is that 'close to' (and here, 'closer to') is a multi-word preposition, and prepositions prototypically take nouns / nounal ing-forms as complements. Not tensed verb-forms or infinitives.